# AT&T vs. Verizon iPhone video playback

Tags: iphone, html, video

I have a set of videos that are encoded for html5, and the videos are playing correctly on AT&T iPhones, but do not play on Verizon iPhones.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and, if so, has anyone found a solution?

Comment: What happens if someone answers "Yes"? (Or "No" for that matter.) How much better off will you be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verizon have actually [publicly admitted](https://ecache.vzw.com/imageFiles/Myacct/nda/images/docs/VerizonWirelessServiceInformation.pdf)(PDF) to compressing images and videos before serving them up to mobile customers. Although this should not cause issues it may go some way to explain why your videos wont play on a Verizon network. Do your videos still suffer if you try to stream them over a WiFi network rather than the mobile data connection?

Comment: It seems like there is a cap on the file size over the 3G network. The video in question played fine on WiFi. Smaller videos played fine on 3G, but the video in question is about 22MB.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between AT&T and Verizon do not play a role in wether or not the video plays one way or another on either device. iOS is the same through and through with the minor differences in carrier related features. Either way it would not affect the playback of video on the device.

Try restoring both devices to factory settings and installing the app on the devices.

Comment: Understood. I'm familiar with that fact that the network provider should have no bearing on iOS functionality. This is, however, the very clear pattern that I found. BTW, it's not an application trying to run the videos, it's in mobile Safari.

Comment: If the video is running in Safari, then you need to take e a look at what all the devices have installed, how many apps are running in the background and how much space the devices have left. These could play a role in the video performance, especially if the videos are running in Safari and it is not app related.